# Is it possible to add multiple smoothed order lines in the same lmplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, smoothing, lmplot

I would like to show multiple smoothed order lines in the same graph using `lmplot` from `seaborn`. For example I would like to show an smoothed order line of 1 and 5 colored in the same graph. Here are two example graphs I would like to have combined in one:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", order = 1, ci = None, truncate = True, data=tips)
```

Output `order = 1`:

[image]

```
sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", order = 5, ci = None, truncate = True, data=tips)
```

Output `order = 5`:

[image]

So I would like to show these two lines in one graph with a legend. It is not supported to have a list as input for the `order` argument. Does anyone know if it is possible to show multiple smoothed order lines in the same graph using `lmplot` from `seaborn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give use `regplot` (which `lmplot` is based on), and initialise an Axes object first, in which case it will just get the current Axes and plot on it. You can probably do this with `lmplot` too, just too lazy to figure it out...

```
_, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.regplot(label='order=1', order=1, x="total_bill", y="tip"...etc)
sns.regplot(label='order=5', order=5, x="total_bill", y="tip"...etc)
plt.legend()
```

[image]